# Meteor/React/ApolloServer/BodyParser - Payload too large

Tags: meteor, apollo, body-parser, apollo-server

I am trying to save quite a big object thanks to a Mutation object in my meteor/react app but I am getting a Payload too large error in the console :

> PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

I know my object is more than the 100kb which is the default limit for bodyparser but I can not managed to have it changed.

I have tried the following while initiating the Apollo Server:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
        return ({
            user: await getUser(req.headers.authorization)
        })

    }
})

server.applyMiddleware({
    app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
  path: '/graphql'
})

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/graphql', (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        res.end()
  }
})
```

But I am still getting the same error. I think my object is around 400kb. I am hoping one of you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apollo-server-express` already includes `body-parser` so you shouldn't add it again as middleware. Instead, you can pass `body-parser` options to Apollo when calling `applyMiddlware`:

```
server.applyMiddleware({
  app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
  path: '/graphql',
  bodyParserConfig: {
    limit: '100mb',
  },
})
```

See the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server#apolloserverapplymiddleware) for a full list of available options.

Comment: this is not working, anybody has the same problem?